# Role assigning is not working properly in laravel spatie?

Tags: laravel

I have three roles in my application:-
super_admin
airtel_admin
quora_admin

This is how i am assigning role:-

```
public function assign_role(Request $request, $id)
    {
        // return $request;
        $request->validate([
            'role' => 'required|not_in:0',
        ]);
        $user = User::find($id);
        // return $user;
        if ($user->assignRole($request->role)) {
            return redirect()->back()->with('message', 'Role Assigned!');
        } else {
            return redirect()->back()->with('error', 'Something Went Wrong!');
        }
    }
```

When I am assigning a role super_admin to any other it working. But after this I am unable to change role super_admin to any other roles(airtel_admin,quora_admin).
and airtel_admin to quora_admin and quora_admin to airtel_admin also working.
What I am doing wrong in this?

Comment: `assignRole` assigns a single or multiple role. are you trying to `sync` instead??

Comment: Problem was I  was not removing current role of the user before assigning new role. When I have done this it's working fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can assign a role to the user via Role name or Role model instance.

```php
$user = User::find($id);
if ( $user->assignRole(
   Role::find($request->id)
) ) {
   // do something
} else {
   // do something
}
```

You can check more details in [official documentation](https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-permission/v5/introduction)

Comment: Thanks for answer Mitesh Rathod.
But the problem was I  was not removing current role of the user before assigning new role. When I have done this it's working fine.